# Python3 Pysmb Random Access Remote Shared File

Tags: python-3.x, random, url-rewriting, shared, smb

I am working with pysmb library.
I know I can retrieve remote shared file using retrieveFile function, and upload local file to remote server using function storeFile.
Then is there a way to random access the remote file?
For exemple, there is a file called 'test.txt' in the server, I want to open it firstly, and then write some records into it from any offset. It is to update content, not the clear and re-write operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Current pysmb release 1.1.14 doesn't support this yet, please refer to comment 41-44 in page [MikeTeo.net](https://miketeo.net/wp/index.php/projects/pysmb/comment-page-1#comment-230256) . It may be supported in later release.

A reminder that since Version 1.1.15, this enhancement is implemented.

Answer (score 0):

```
from io import BytesIO

myoffset = 18 # Mention the bytes from where you want to start writing file
file_obj = io.BytesIO(b"updated line \n")
filesize = SambaConnection.storeFileFromOffset(
                  "My-Samba-Share-Name", 
                  "/myfile.txt", 
                  file_obj, 
                  offset=myoffset
               )
```